# Why does Scalaz \/ type have getOrElse but not get?

Tags: scala, scalaz

As far as I can tell Scalaz's `\/` does not have `get` method. Sometimes I am sure the value contained in `\/` is the right value, and I don't want to use `getOrElse`. I want to get it directly.

```
("3".right[Int]) getOrElse("123123123") // 3

if (t.isRight) t.get // compilation error, no get method
```

How can I get the right value directly, if it is guaranteed.

There are two ways I can get the value, but both look a little bit verbose.

**1: change to scala Either**

```
val t = "3".right[Int]
val either = t.toEither

if (either.isRight) either.right.get
else either.left.get
```

**2: Use getOrElse**

```
("3".right[Int]) getOrElse("123123123") // but for some cases I don't have this default value
```

Comment: Is there a map method?

Comment: but map still use right projection, the return type of map is still \/ type instead of the type of the right value.

Comment: If you desperately need to perform an unsafe get, you can always just do something like `getOrElse(sys.error("No such element"))`. This really is the same as doing a get, just more explicit about what happens when there is no value ( => exception )

Comment: The surprising thing is that Scalaz provides `isRight`.

Comment: In regards to #1, pattern match on `-\/`/`\/-` or use fold https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.1.0/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Either.scala#L54

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no get as get *could* throw an exception, which isn't cool. Scalaz enforces this by not allowing direct access to the value.

If you provide more information, we can help out with a solution.

```
t should be safe.

val safe_thing:T = ???
val either: Throwable \/ T = getFromSomewhere

either getOrElse safe_thing
```

Comment: I dont think so, my understanding is if either is already checked if it is right, it should get directly. Also, getOrElse(t), t may throw exception as well.

Comment: t should be safe.

val safe_thing:T = ???
val either: Throwable \/ T = getFromSomewhere

Comment: @Cloudtech How do you check it ? Via pattern matching? Then you already have the value.

Answer (score 0):

As other answer pointed out, `get` *could* throw. But similarly to OP, I also encountered cases when I was sure of a type (in this case `\/-`), yet the variable in code was of type `\/` (super class).

Doing inline pattern matching was very verbose and looked bad.

```
  println(("test".right[String] |> { case \/-(x) => x; case _ => "" }).toUpperCase)
```

So I wrote this helper:

```
  implicit class ScalazDisjunctionPimps[A, B](e: \/[A, B]) {
    def getRight: B = e match {
      case \/-(x) => x
      case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"$e is not right.")
    }
  }
```

Usage is simple, here's example:

```
  println("test".right.getRight.toUpperCase) // outputs: TEST
```

If needed `getLeft` can be constructed in the same way.